# Iridium carbides in stainless steel alloys

Tags: condensed-matter, metals

> Has there ever been any high carbon stainless steel made with iridium as one of the alloy components? Is there any research in this direction?

There is a [paper](https://inis.iaea.org/search/search.aspx?orig_q=RN:48005328) from 2016 comparing various iridium structures to more well known/studied structures, with the finding that iridium dinitrogen exhibits the highest bulk modulus of any high pressure synthesized compound at 428GPa.

There is also a [paper](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/jp112308t) from 2011 studying various physical properties of iridium carbides with various stoichiometries, finding that iridium pentacarbide and iridium tetracarbide (with iridium germanide structures) are potential ultrahard materials.

Has any more work been done in this area, ideally looking towards applications for iridium as a component in high carbon stainless steel alloys?

Comment: Today’s iridium price is $6,100 per Troy ounce. Interesting, but expensive idea.

Comment: The Fe-Ir phase diagram shows continuous solid solubility over a broad temperature range. So one would need a deeper analysis to see if you would even make iridium carbides in a Fe-Ir-C ternary. Further, there are limits to the applicability of ultra-hard particles on grain boundaries - once you get to hard-enough you don't need to go further. (Then there is the cost as pointed out above).

Comment: But I find no literature on such experiments.